# Регулярные выражение: проверить ссылку

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Помогите проверить ссылку

http://cs410101.vk.me/u11185802/a_аad503a9.jpg

1. начитанется с **http://cs**
2. далее идут **цифры 0-9**
3. далее строка **.vk.me/**
4. заканчивается ссылка **.jpg**

пытаюсь как то так

```
preg_match("/^http://cs[0-9](.vk.me/)[.](.jpg)/", $photo)
```

спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^http://cs[0-9]+\.vk\.me/[^.]+\.jpg$
```

[Regexp tester](http://regexpal.com/) вам в помощь.

Comment: if (preg_match("^http://cs[0-9]+\.vk\.me/[.]+\.jpg$", $DATA['photo'])) {
    echo "ok";
} else
    echo "no";

что то не работает Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in

Comment: Ой, ну вот не надо...

    <?php
    $string = 'http://cs410101.vk.me/u11185802/a_аad503a9.jpg';
    $regexp = '/^http:\/\/cs[0-9]+\.vk\.me\/[^.]+\.jpg$/';
    if(preg_match($regexp,$string)){
 print 'ok';
    }

Comment: спасибо, работает!

    /^http:\/\/cs[0-9]+\.vk\.me\/[^.]+\.jpg$/